# Multiple write access to volatile int variable

Tags: c#, multithreading

Is it safe to have multiple threads writing to a `volatile int` variable at the same time?

It is not clear for me from the corresponding MSDN page.

Comment: It may be worth reading Eric Lippert's information on the topic: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2011/06/16/atomicity-volatility-and-immutability-are-different-part-three/

Comment: What does "safe" mean? Is it safe if it doesn't segfault the process? or were you looking for a stronger guarantee than that?

Answer (score 0):

`volatile` keyword disallows any optimizations on specified variable and probably doesnt allow caching it by other threads.

When you are reading variable while other threads are writing to it would be reasonable to use this keyword. You can also wrap it around object, apply `lock` keyword and then read it. It really depends on what are you doing.